# Plot datetime.time values on x axis using axvline

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, axvline

I am trying to use the axvline function to plot datetime.time values and seeing this error. please help.

```
time_ret = datetime.time(11,15)
ax1 = axvline(time_ret, ...)
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.time'
```

I see a lot of solution to this issue but all of them answer to this issue by plotting axvline on datetime.date.

I have added a code for the reference. Please help

Comment: Could you expand your code to show us the full traceback of the error and the full call to `axvline`? And why do the other solutions not work (couldn't you just use `datetime.date` instead of `datetime.time`)?

Comment: `enter code here`

>import datetime as dt
>from datetime import datetime
>import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

>i='wpt'
>x = [datetime.time(12,10,10), datetime.time(12, 10, 10)]
>axs[i].axvline(x[0], color = 'lightskyblue', ls = '--', lw = 1)